# Find if libbdd is installed

Tags: cmake

I'm writing cmake build script and I want to check if user installed libbdd library (installed by `sudo apt-get install libbdd-dev`). I tried using the following `find_package(libbdd)` but it doesn't find the lib even though it is installed. How to properly check if lib is installed?

Comment: Does the file FindLibbdd.cmake exist? If yes, where does it come from? I think you have write your own check using `find_library`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_package` works if either:

1. Someone provides `findXXX.cmake` script, which search library in its default location.
2. The library shipped with `XXXConfig.cmake` script.

Otherwise, you need to resort to other methods.

E.g., if library has support for `pkg-config` utility, you may use CMake module [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html?highlight=pkgconfig) for detect it.

---

If you want just to **check**, whether library is installed into **default location**, you may check that its *signature* header file may be included into the program. The simplest way to do this is to use [CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckIncludeFile.html):

```
# Include mModule, where the macro is declared.
include(CheckIncludeFile)
# Check that header file is accessible.
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE("bdd.h" # "Signature" header for the library libbdd.
    BDD_INSTALLED # Variable to store result
)
if(NOT BDD_INSTALLED)
    # Remove FALSE value from the cache, so next run
    # the include file will be rechecked.
    #
    # Without removing, CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE will check nothing at next run.
    unset(BDD_INSTALLED CACHE)

    message(SEND_ERROR "Unable to detect 'bdd' library. Install libbdd-dev and rerun cmake.")
endif(NOT BDD_INSTALLED)

# Assume that libbdd is installed.
```

Comment: Apparently the library doesn't support `pkg-config` so I ended up checking if there is a file in the `/usr/include` (that is where it gets stored after installing it using `apt-get`. Would this be considered as a bad solution?

Comment: You may use `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE` for that purpose. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this looks and feels much better. Thanks!